# Swashbuckle, Swagger and WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

I have a webapi running (.net 4.5) with Help pages loading all my xml comments via the ApiExplorer. I want to now add swagger via swashbuckle. So I installed the swashbuckle nuget but when I browse to my endpoint I get an error as suggested by swashbuckle documentation..

endpoint: localhost:1234/api/company/swagger
error: {"Message":"Unauthorized request"}
or
endpoint: localhost:1234/api/company/swagger/apidocs
error: 404 - Not Found

Am I missing a step or waht am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade its pre-release version

In PMC

```
Update-Package Swashbuckle.Core -Pre
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit old but see if this helps:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Taken from https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.  I cannot explain what it does as I do not have enough knowledge about web.config or Swashbuckle but after adding this, I was able to see the docs.  When I had originally added Swashbuckle in my project, I was able to see the documentation.  I do not know if I made any changes to Web.config after initially adding the nuget package.

Comment: After reading the description, it may help.  I sort of understand why the routing needs to be there but not completely.  In order to make it work for my own project, I ended up doing this:     <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>

Answer (score 0):

Install Swashbuckle.Core and be sure that App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs is created

Answer (score 0):

- Install-Package Swashbuckle in visual studio package manager console

---

- after that type Swagger after slash of localhost
  like http://localhost:52940/Swagger